# JavaScript async/await for Promises inside Array.map()

Tags: javascript, async-await, babeljs, es6-promise, ecmascript-next

Given the following code

```
class SomeClass {
  async someFunc() {
    const urlParameters = [0, 1, 2];
    const batchAjaxResult = await urlParameters.map((parameter) => { 
        const result = await $.get(`someUrl/${parameter}`);
        return {
          parameter,
          result
        }
     });

  console.log(batchAjaxResult);

  }
}
```

JavaScript will return an Array of resolved Promises instead of the actual Promises result.

This is probably due to `Array.map()` not being implemented as a Promise.

Is there a Promise-based version of `Array.map`?

This is question differs from [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), because it's about How to return batched responses wrapped inside `Array.map`.

Comment: Specifically look towards the bottom of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30180679/542251)

Comment: @Liam I'm already using the mentioned ES7 async/await syntax. The problem only occurs when Array.map'ing over them. `const X = await Array.map(...)` seems to not be implemented yet.

Comment: You can only `await` a promise, not an array. Try `await Promise.all(array)`.

Answer (score 3):

By writing this question I managed to get down to the root of the problem.

It seems like Bluebird has such an feature called [`Promise.map`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html)

Similarily there is a native implementation called [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) that creates a "bulk Promise"

I changed the code as follows and it's working:

```
class SomeClass {
  async someFunc() {
      const urlParameters = [0, 1, 2];
      const batchAjaxResult = await Promise.all(
          urlParameters.map(async (parameter) => {
            const result = await $.get(`someUrl/${parameter}`);
            return {
              parameter,
              result
            }
         })
      );
      console.log(batchAjaxResult);

  }
}
```

Comment: The arrow function itself has to be async too.

Comment: "it's working" --- it's doubtfully, since it has a syntax error.

Comment: sorry, yes the arrow function needs to be async. I have fixed the code

Answer (score 3):

You could use this simple function which chains the promises to achieve sequential execution:

```js
function asyncMap(arr, mapper) {
  var q = Promise.resolve();
  return Promise.all(arr.map(v => q = q.then(() => mapper(v))));
}


// Usage

asyncMap([1, 2, 3], v => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log("Start " + v);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("End " + v);
      resolve("foo" + v);
    }, 500);
  });
}).then(a => console.log(a));
```

Comment: yes, but I was looking for parallel execution. You don't want to see your browser load data into the UI one by one.

Comment: @TobiasMühl Okay, it's best to mention these kind of things in the question itself.